# Directly send data to Java class from JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Is there any way of passing data to JAVA class from a JSP page without using Servlets? I have a form which i send to JAVA class without using servlet. Also I don't want to use Struts1 for this purpose.

Please guide me.

Comment: Well, JSP pages are servlets under the hood, so you are already using servlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different ways of calling java code from JSP pages

1. Call Java code directly

   Place all Java code in JSP page, scriptlets. Appropriate only for very small amounts of code.
2. Call Java code indirectly

   Develop separate utility classes. Insert into JSP page just the Java code needed to invoke the utility classes.
3. Use beans (Standard actions)

   Develop separate utility classes structured as beans. Use jsp:useBean, jsp:getProperty, and jsp:setProperty to invoke the code.
4. Use the MVC architecture

   *I see that you don't want to use servlets.*
5. Use the JSP EL

   Use shorthand syntax to access and output object properties. Usually used in conjunction with beans and MVC.
6. Use custom tags

   Develop tag handler classes or use a tag library(JSTL).

Answer (score 0):

Servlet is a good option to club up with jsp - why are you neglecting it ?
check out scriptlet tag `<% %>` `<%= %>`